# Can I see where my Teradata stored procedure is failing?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a stored procedure in Teradata that used to work but some changes recently have rendered the output of the procedure non-existent. Partial code is pasted below in-case anyone can find the error or how to turn off the error handling. But what I'm looking for here is a way to track the error in the procedure.  If I try to run the individual elements of the procedure separately they fail and if I run the full procedure it runs but doesn't tell me where it failed and moved on.

Is there a way in Teradata to see where things are going wrong?

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE HP_FL_OWN.RX_INITIATIVES_UM_SP()

BEGIN
        DECLARE VAR_DB_NAME, VAR_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(60);
        DECLARE ACT_INFO VARCHAR(1000);
        DECLARE STEP_NAME VARCHAR(100);
        DECLARE ACT_NAME VARCHAR(100);
        DECLARE ACT_ID INT; 

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Error Handling step
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /*  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SqlException */
        BEGIN

                SELECT SqlState INTO ACT_INFO;
            --  SET ACT_INFO=SqlState;
                
                -- if error occurs in 01 or 02
                IF STEP_NAME IN('01-Verify EDW Completion', '02-Verify Current Execution')THEN 
                    -- insert error log record for step 01 or step 02
                    CALL HP_FL_OWN.OPR_ACTIVITY_LOG_INSERT_SP(ACT_NAME, Current_Timestamp(0), 'E',STEP_NAME,'ERROR_SQLSTATE:'||ACT_INFO,ACT_ID);--create record in log table for the day
                
                ELSE -- if error occurs in any other step
                    -- update error log record with that step
                    CALL HP_FL_OWN.OPR_ACTIVITY_LOG_UPDATE_SP(ACT_ID,'E',STEP_NAME,'ERROR_SQLSTATE:'||ACT_INFO);---update record in log table when process completes
                
                END IF;
                
        END;
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Begin SP 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried looking at the history but it does not involved any detailed info on what line(s) are failing.

Comment: You would normally manage errors by including error handling in your stored procedure. Not really sure what you are asking - you say the SPs you are calling error if you call them directly, but I’m assuming you aren’t asking why they’re erroring as you haven’t included any information about them or the errors

Comment: I didn't write this code initially. There's error handling language in the query (I pasted that piece) but this error handling is keeping me from knowing where the query is failing since it is ultimately failing.

Comment: I don’t really understand your last comment as there’s no error handling in what you’ve put in your question. If the SPs this SP is calling also don’t have error handling then if they error then this calling SP won’t be aware of it - but then you have no code in this calling SP to handle anything returned by those SPs. I’m also still not clear whether your question is about how to write error handling code or whether you’re trying to find out (and fix) what is causing the specific error you are seeing (for which you’ve provided no details)

Comment: Trying to find a log of errors for the procedure. Finding line by line where it failed. As it stands now it just runs through ignoring errors and ending up with nothing as a results.

Comment: To "turn off error handling" you would need to comment the entire block, not just the DECLARE EXIT HANDLER clause. Otherwise it's going to CALL the HP_FL_OWN.OPR_ACTIVITY_LOG_UPDATE_SP procedure before it does anything else.